# How do i make the code below check if neighboring numbers have a difference of one?

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1
Dim jumbled As Integer = 0
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("enter a number: ")
    Dim neighno As String = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim Neighncount As Integer = neighno.Count
```

'This part of the code should go through each letter that the user entered,go to the number after and the number before in each loop convert it to integer and add one then check if this number equals the current C value '

```
    For Each c As String In neighno
        If neighno(c).Equals(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(neighno(c + 1))) - 1) Or neighno(c).Equals(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(neighno(c + 1))) + 1) Then
            jumbled = jumbled + 1
        End If
    Next
```

' an error for the index being outside of the array's bounds is also shown whenever the code is run'

```
    If jumbled = neighncount Then
        Console.WriteLine("jumbled")
        Console.ReadLine()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not jumbled")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Can you write a function that takes two numbers and returns bool indicating whether the numbers have a difference of one?

Comment: Finally (question already asked, different account) set `Option Strict On` and you're going to immediately find out what's wrong with that code. After that, set `Option Strict` to `ON` as the default value in the configuration `Options` of your Visual Studio.